# Number of large terms of a sequence is small

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My question is this: let $\{a_{n}\}_{n\geq 1}\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a nonnegative real-valued sequence such that $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n$ converges. For each $j\geq 1$, we define
$$b_j:=|\{n\in \mathbb{N}:a_n\geq 3^{-j}\}|.$$
Prove
$$\limsup_{j\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b_j}{3^j}=0.$$
I tried
$$\limsup_{j\rightarrow\infty}\frac{b_j}{3^j}\leq\limsup_{j\rightarrow \infty}b_j\cdot\limsup_{j\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{3^j} ` `="\infty\cdot 0$$
as well as observing that $\exists N$ such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $a_n<\frac{1}{3}$, so $b_1\leq N$, but these approaches didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $j\geq1$, let $B_j = \lbrace n \in \mathbb{N}^* \text{ }| \text{ } a_n \geq 3^{-j} \rbrace$, and let $B_0 = \emptyset$.

Let $S=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} a_n$. Rearranging the terms, and forgetting those which are zero, you have
$$S = \sum_{j=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{n \in Bj \setminus B_{j-1}} a_n$$

So $$S \geq \sum_{j=1}^{+\infty} \frac{b_j - b_{j-1}}{3^j}$$

So for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $$S \geq \sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{b_j - b_{j-1}}{3^j} = \frac{b_1}{3} +\sum_{j=2}^N \frac{b_j}{3^j} - \sum_{j=2}^N \frac{b_{j-1}}{3^j}$$
$$=\frac{b_1}{3} +\sum_{j=2}^N \frac{b_j}{3^j} - \sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \frac{b_{j}}{3^{j+1}}$$ $$ = \frac{b_1}{3} +\sum_{j=2}^{N-1} b_j \left(\frac{1}{3^j}- \frac{1}{3^{j+1}}\right) + \frac{b_n}{3^n} - \frac{b_1}{9}$$
$$ \geq \sum_{j=2}^{N-1} b_j \left(\frac{1}{3^j}- \frac{1}{3^{j+1}}\right) = \frac{2}{3}\sum_{j=2}^{N-1} \frac{b_j}{3^j}$$

Therefore the series $\sum \frac{b_j}{3^j}$ converges, so in particular,
$$\lim_{j \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{b_j}{3^j} = 0$$